# Appium - Testing multiplayer features

Tags: appium

Hello I just wanted to know if it is possible to test two devices at the same time using appium. Having more than one driver for different devices. For example:
iphoneDevice.clickSomething()
androidDevice.shouldSeeSomething()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test 2 devices at the same time without any issues, just create driver instance / session for each device providing the unique device [UDID](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) and other required iOS/Android values in capabilities.

Starting with v **1.7.0** Appium server [supports multiple concurrent sessions](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.7.0), so you can use a single server instance.